# Finding the sample mean for x and y

Tags: statistics

Fred is conducting a survey and he wants to know whether people's weight relates to the number of times they drink soda per day. He surveys $50$ people.

Let $X$=the number of times a person drinks soda per day

Let $Y$=People's weight.

Find the sample mean using the data from the chart.

[image]

I couldn't fit all the data points but I want to be able to do this problem myself anyways.

If I have to find the sample mean, am I going to have two different sample means? One for drinks and one for weight?

For drinks: I would add up all the data points and divide by $50$

For weight: I would add up all the weights divide by $50$

I am confused because these data points are dependent(i think)  on each other so I'm not sure how to work with two variables

Also would the sample mean be the population mean in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would indeed use the approach you described: just calculate the sample mean for each variable (drinks and weight).  The sample mean is something that really pertains to one variable only.  To investigate the dependency of the two variables on one another you would use something like the correlation coefficient.

As for your second question: I personally have big problems with how (inconsistently) statisticians call things.  It however seems to be consensus that population simply means "all your data points" and sample "a part of your population".  Since in this case you are calculating the means using all data points, I would say sample mean and population mean are the same (in this instance).

Answer (score 1):

There is the implicit assumption that soda consumption may cause obesity (or not, but many people are interested in investigating that sense of the relationship). Then X becomes the 'independent' variable and Y is the focus of the sample, hence the term sample average is likely to refer to average weight. This is rather subjective, one might imagine a parallel world where a larger weight actually *causes* soda consumption.

Population would refer to a large, presumably unmeasurable group such as all adults in Europe. The population mean is unknown but the sample mean is used to estimate it.

Comment: In order to perform even simple linear regression you would have to calculate the sample means of both the dependent and independent variables. Hence, calculating only $\bar{Y}$ would not be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use curve fitting to solve the problem (it is not necessarily a linear problem) use excel to graph the data as a scatter plot and decide what function is appropriate (there are some more advanced and fancy functions that excel offer I can't help you there though as i don't know them all) but I would believe that an exp function should do the trick in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking whether your two data sets are correlated.  Most numerical analysis books will have a discussion.  [Numerical Recipes](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html) discusses ways to check correlation in section 14.4 and whether there is a linear relationship in section 14.5.  You can use the chi-square test to see if knowing the value of one variable helps you predict the value of the other.

Generally the population would be all the people that your $50$ were drawn from.  The population means would be the weight and number of drinks averaged over everybody.  You do not have access to that.  The sample means are the averages of your $50$ data points.  Assuming you have drawn your sample randomly, you can hope the sample mean is close to the population mean.  If the distribution is normal, you can compute how close it should be.